# PowerShell - finding users who are Inactive AND not disabled

Tags: active-directory, powershell, user-accounts, organizational-unit

I wrote this cmdlet:

```
Search-ADAccount -filter {(enabled -eq $true)} -Users Only -SearchBase "ou=FirstOU,dc=domain,dc=com" -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 30
```

But it outputs an error:

```
Search-ADAccount : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'fil
ter'.
At line:1 char:25
+ Search-ADAccount -filter <<<<  {(enabled -eq $true)} -UsersOnly -SearchBase "
ou=FirstOU,dc=domain,dc=com" -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 30
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Search-ADAccount], Paramet
   erBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory
   .Management.Commands.SearchADAccountCmdlet
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter it the other way?:

```
Search-ADAccount -UsersOnly -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 30.00:00:00 |where {$_.enabled}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `Search-ADAccount` does not accept a parameter `-Filter`. Please see the [Technet docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617247.aspx) or `Get-Help Search-ADAccount` for a list of supported parameters.

You can pipe the results of the search to `Where-Object` to get only enabled users:

```
Search-ADAccount -UsersOnly -SearchBase "ou=FirstOU,dc=domain,dc=com" -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 30 |
    Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq $true }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the get-ADUser command, it allows you to filter your users better.

get-aduser -filter (enabled -eq $true) -searchbase "OU"